# problemas al intentar sumar resultado de un COUNT MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

hola amigos tengo un problema es lo siguiente tengo dos tablas una que es lideres y otra que es votantes y están relacionadas pero quiero hacer una consulta para saber cual es la cantidad de votantes por líder lo hice así:

```
SELECT l.cc_lider,COUNT(v.cc_lider) AS total FROM lideres l 
LEFT JOIN votantes19 v ON l.cc_lider = v.cc_lider GROUP BY l.cc_lider
```

y funciona bien pero yo quiero sumar el resultado de cada COUNT de cada líder
 como se ve en la imagen quiero que sume el 0,2 y 1 y no encuentro la solución

[image: como se ve en la imagen quiero que sume el 0,2 y 1 y no encuentro la solución]

lo intente así:

```
SELECT l.cc_lider,COUNT(v.cc_lider) AS total, SUM(total) FROM lideres l 
LEFT JOIN votantes19 v ON l.cc_lider = v.cc_lider GROUP BY l.cc_lider
```

y no funciona, también encontré algo así:

```
 SELECT l.cc_lider, SUM(COUNT(v.cc_lider)) as total FROM lideres l      
 LEFT JOIN votantes19 v ON l.cc_lider = v.cc_lider GROUP BY l.cc_lider
```

y nada no doy con la solución. para poder sumar el total.

Comment: Intenta hacer una subconsulta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se puede en SQL sumar el resultado de funciones de agregación que estén sobre el mismo SELECT. Simplemente el resultado del COUNT() no existe aún al momento de ejecutarse el SUM().

Para lograr lo que quieres tienes que hacerlo a partir de una tabla derivada generada por la consulta de conteo, es decir que la operación de conteo debe ser la subconsulta de donde tomas los resultados
Pero no me queda claro si lo que quieres es la cuenta final, la sumatoria de los resultados. Si es así tampoco es esa la forma, debes usar el ROLLUP

```
SELECT l.cc_lider,COUNT(v.cc_lider) total
FROM lideres l 
  LEFT JOIN votantes19 v ON l.cc_lider = v.cc_lider 
GROUP BY l.cc_lider WITH ROLLUP
```

El manual de referencia es bastante claro en esto: [MySQL Refman: 12.20.2 GROUP BY Modifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, esa solución que me diste me funciona!. básicamente lo que estoy haciendo es sacar la suma de votantes relacionados con un lider y después sumar los totales de votantes por lider

Comment: Me alegra que te sirva.
Ten presente siempre el manual de referencia, porque ni los expertos se ponen a memorizar todo.